# Update in sales order table - Magento Model

Tags: magento

I want to update one field value in magento I am using

```
$data = array('xxx'=>$xxx);
$orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId)->addData($data);
try {
    $orderModel->setId($orderId)->save();
    echo "Data updated successfully.";
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But it is not working, Any one can suggest me what I am doing the create problem in updating data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the **MAGIC** function, `get` and `set` function

try directly:

```
// if your attribute is column named is_active then you can getIsActive() or setIsActive(1)
$orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId)->setYourAttribute($data);
// it means you can set and get column named by ['your_attribute']
try {
    $orderModel->setId($orderId)->save();
    echo "Data updated successfully.";
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

hmmm. i don't know why you set the entity_id of sales/order model. but it won't work because the entity_id can be the foreign key on another table, example : `sales_flat_order_payment`

Answer (score 1):

Your code `setId($orderId)` looks like you either want to explicitely set an order `entity_id` (that is, create an order), or you're just not aware of the fact, that you don't need `setId($orderId)` after loading, if you only want to update the given order.

In case you're trying to create an order: the `sales/order` model normally does *not* allow to explicitely set an order's `entity_id`, because it uses a primary key being auto-incremented by default.

In case you're trying to update an existing order: remove the `setId($orderId)` from the `save()` chain.

Second, you need to extend the `sales/order` model with an `xxx` attribute first, if you want to be able to save its value to the database.

There are several ways to extend the `sales/order` model to have a custom attribute. For example you could have your own setup script in your `app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/sql/myresource/` folder:

```
// Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
$oInstaller = $this;

// Add EAV attribute
$oInstaller->startSetup();
$oInstaller->addAttribute(
    'order',
    'my_attribute',
    array(
        'type' => 'int'
    )
);
$oInstaller->endSetup();

// Add flat attribute
if (Mage::getVersion() >= 1.1) {
    $oInstaller->startSetup();
    $oConnection = $oInstaller->getConnection();
    $oConnection->addColumn(
        $oInstaller->getTable('sales_flat_order'),
        'my_attribute',
        'TINYINT(1) NOT NULL'
    );
    $oInstaller->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i will try this and let you know :)